Managing the convenience of downloading data to your laptop VS the security risk of having data in a laptop that is less secure than the cloud
As datascientists and ML engineers, we have often pulled data into our laptops to explore and even to prototype models. But laptops are are not secure as services within the company's cloud, and this opens up the risk of potential data exfiltration (accidental or not).
Curious, what process or tools do you use at your places to manage this convenience vs risk tradeoff?
I understand these processes/tools are going to be different for different verticals and company stages/sizes, because of varying risk profiles.

well u can try using a virtual environment and run everything there if that's what u are concerned about and second u can run the data or files in cloud like sandboxes
and there's always this rule we look out
who u are getting your data from is the first step in the data science life cycle
so there first party(firms data ,data that u collected , etc) , second party(govt websites , reputed data providers etc) and third party(random datasets u find online )  and the highest risk is always with third party data as its not cleaned and might have different procedures
so based on your need u choose and select the process so therefore get your need straight and u are good to go
